How to sum the specific column in SheetJs?
I have here an export button wherein I total column of Departments

Currently what I'm trying to do is sum the column of AG from AG:2 to AG:21 wherein the sum will be at A:22.
  const handleExportExcel = () => {
    const data = zoomDataQuery.data.data;
    const month = zoomDataQuery.data.month;
  
    // Get the departments
   const departments = Object.keys(data);
    
    // Get the number of days in the month
   // const daysInMonth = Object.keys(data[departments[0]]).length;
    const daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(new Date())


    // Create the header row
    const header: (string | number)[] = ["Department", ...Array.from({length: daysInMonth}, (_, i) => i + 1), "Department Total"];
    
    // Create the rows for each department
    const rows: (string | number)[][] = departments.map(dept => {
      const row: (string | number)[] = [dept];
      let deptTotal = 0;
      
      for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
        const value = data[dept][i.toString()] || null;
        row.push(value);
        deptTotal += value;
      }
      
      row.push(deptTotal);
      return row;
    });

    

    
    // Create a new workbook and worksheet
    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([header, ...rows]);
    
    // Set column widths
    const colWidth = 5;
    const firstColWidth = 15;
    const lastColWidth = 20;
    ws['!cols'] = [
      { wch: firstColWidth },
      ...Array(daysInMonth).fill({ wch: colWidth }),
      { wch: lastColWidth }
    ];
    
    // Append the worksheet to the workbook
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Departments");
    
    // Export the Excel file
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, `${month}_DEPARTMENT_REPORT.xlsx`);
  };

